# How to avoid Attiny84 being powered on by a pulled up data line?

Tags: arduino, serial, attiny, pullup

I've developed a simple sensor board based on the Attiny84a microcontroller which is able to communicate over a serial connection. I'm using an arduino bootloader and the SoftwareSerial library on pins 5 (RX) and 3 (TX). 
I would like to be able to keep the serial line attached while power cycling the sensor. But it seems that the Attiny84 is powered through the RX line of the Serial connection, which is pulled high by the other communication partner.

It seems the RX line is pulled to 3.4 volts when nothing is attached and I can measure 1.4V across the Attiny84's Vcc and GND pins when the serial line is attached. Apparently that is sufficient to turn it on, since my debug LED starts flashing dimly.

Is there a simple way to keep the Attiny84 off even when the serial cable is attached?

Comment: Series resistor on the data line? Or a load resistor on the power supply lines parallel to the AVR, but mind you your dataline *will* be loaded. It is caused by the protective diodes on the chip, you can't change that.

Comment: If you find a good solution I'd be happy to know, this has always bothered me and I have just lived with it. Basically by the time I had everything else on the circuit board, it would draw off enough power that the ATMega/Tiny would be below the reset threshold.

Comment: It is bad design practice, other chips may latch up and selfdestruct under these conditions (power on i/o pins before supply pins 
have power applied).

Comment: So you're saying a series resistor on the data line is bad design practice since the I/O pin is still pulled high? It seems the most simple approach and I can confirm that it works in my case. Out of curiosity, what sort of chip is it that could self destruct?

Comment: What is the value of the pull up resistor? May I dare suggest that it's simply a matter of increasing it so that there is insufficient current to power the attiny?

Comment: In my case it worked fine with a 1k resistor, which should limit the current to about 3mA. The diode solution is cleaner though since it blocks unwanted current instead of just reducing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the margins you have available, this might work for you. It allows the Rx signal to draw the ATTiny Rx input down to 0.6-0.7V, but does not allow current to flow back into the processor. The node "ATTiny VCC" is switched on and off with the processor. If this is 5V (rather than 3.3V) you need to size the resistor so that it doesn't cause backflow problems in the Rx circuit.

If 0.6V is too high to trigger a good LOW in the ATTiny, you might use a low-drop diode like a Schottky or a germanium.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXn1im.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Easy to implement and works like a charm in my case. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think that diode will block current flow to the input

Comment: Yes, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because there are internal protection diodes on the GPIO pins so any voltage that comes in is shunted to the internal power rail...

[image]

Even though these are little diodes, this chip uses so little power that it is often enough to run it. This is the source of one of the [top-10 hardest bugs](http://wp.josh.com/2014/03/03/the-mystery-of-the-zombie-ram/) I've ever hard to find!

### Method #1 - Pull ~RESET Low

As long as the voltage on the ~RESET pin is less than 0.2*Vcc, then the chip will stay in a reset condition and not running.

[image]

You can connect the ~RESET pin to the power supply pin and use a pull-down resistor to keep the ~RESET pin below the threshold when there is no active power supply.  Note that you need the pull-down because there is an internal pull-up on the ~RESET pin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fShUOL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This method wastes a little current, but will keep the chip in a reset state when it is not actively powered.

Keep in mind that there will be a voltage drop across the diode.

### Method #2 - Isolate Input Pins

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIeehK.png)</sup>

Here we use the power supply to enable the input pin. If there is no voltage coming from the power supply, no significant current to flow into the input pin.

Comment: Are you saying by holding the system in reset that no power can back-flow? I am not sure I have found that to be true.

Comment: Power will still back flow, but the chip will not run - it will be in a RESET state.

Comment: No -1, but I don't think this is really addressing the problem, which is back-powering a chip via its I/O.  It's just masking the symptom.

Comment: Thank you very much for this informative answer! However it seems to me too that #1 doesn't tackle the problem at its root and #2 seems slightly more complicated than the diode solution discussed by Will Dean and Daniel, so I will try theirs first.

Answer (score 1):

If your comms speed is low-enough and your power-budget will allow it, you can often avoid this simply by adding a diode between the RX pin and the outside world (anode to the RX pin, cathode to the outside world), and then having a pull-up resistor on the RX pin (your micro might be able to do this internally).

Then the remote device can only pull the RX pin down, but the pull-up resistor will pull it back up.

You will probably want to use a schottky diode (e.g. BAT54), and you do need to think about the input-low (Vil) levels you'll get at the micro pin - check that they're still OK.

If you can't do it like this, you could use a buffer in that line - selecting a buffer which didn't have this protection-diode-to-VCC behaviour (e.g. 74LVC or one of the others like it - Texas Instruments call this 'Ioff' support - see [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/scyt129f/scyt129f.pdf) for example)

Comment: Uh....... jinx?

Comment: You can't say "jinx" after 5 minutes :-)

Comment: It did take me a bit to actually write my answer out and do the schematic... from my perspective it was simultaneous!

Comment: Yes, I'm much too lazy to do the schematics.